# Grails/MongoDB Why is this field not being saved to the db?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have the following Domain Classes:

```
class Account {

    String id    
    String email
    ...
    Ban ban

    static constraints = {
        ban nullable: true
    }

    static embedded = ['ban']
}

class Ban {
   Date dateBanned
   Account bannedBy
}
```

When i try to create a Ban and saved it in the account, only the dateBanned gets added to the database.

```
def ban = new Ban()
ban.bannedBy = springSecurityService.currentUser
ban.banDate = new Date()
account.ban = ban
account.save()
```

The result is an account with a field ban, but inside only one field, dateBanned, and not bannedBy.

I'm using Grails 2.3.7 (yes i know its dated but have no choice right now)

Is this because it's an account inside an account? 
Because i have other Classes with Accounts there that work perfectly.

Comment: looks like `springSecurityService.currentUser` is null

Comment: @injecteer it's not, with a breakpoint i can see it's all it should be.

Comment: @TiagoSilva is your authentication Domain is account? if not there is can be a case. Also are you using only mongo datasource or sql too?

Comment: was Ban saved? if `springSecurityService.currentUser` was null then it won't save.

Comment: did you try with relation `hasOne` .. `belongsTo` ?

Comment: @Koloritnij not sure i'll have to check

Comment: @devbd i didn't explicit do a save() but it was saved to the db with just one field, dateBanned. And it's not null, i've said that before.

I did try those relationships with the same result